# Django Subquery Error

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.8, django-1.4

I made a migration from Django 1.4 to Django 1.8 and now i have a problem that i dont know how to solve.

When i run:

```
dd_interface =  D_Interface.objects.filter(C_INTERFACE__iexact=interface.c_interface)[:1]
    campos = DD_Interface_Campos.objects.filter(dd_interface = dd_interface).order_by('SEQ')
```

I receive the error:

> NotSupportedError(1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"))

In Django 1.4. the query that is executed in BD (MySQL) is:

SELECT     `dd_interface`.`id`,    `dd_interface`.`dd_interface_id`,
    ......... FROM    `dd_interface` WHERE    `dd_interface`.`dd_interface_id` = (
       SELECT 
           U0.`id`
       FROM
           `dd_interface_extend` U0
       WHERE
           U0.`C_INTERFACE` LIKE 'ORACLE.1123.sdas'
       LIMIT 1) ORDER BY `dd_interface`.`SEQ` ASC

In Django 1.8 is used the "IN" clause that  the MySql 5.X doesnt support.

SELECT 
    `dd_interface`.`id`,
    `dd_interface`.`dd_interface_id`,
FROM
    `dd_interface`
WHERE
    (`dd_interface`.`dd_interface_id`) IN (
        SELECT 
            U0.`id`
        FROM
            `dd_interface_extend` U0
        WHERE
            U0.`C_INTERFACE` LIKE 'ORACLE.1123.sdas'
        LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY `dd_interface`.`SEQ` ASC

How can i pass this problem ? (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do `filter(dd_interface=dd_interface)` where `dd_interface` is a queryset and not a model instance. Why are you using `[:1]` instead of [0] (or just `.get()`)? What do you want to happen if the first query does not return any items?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm starting my studies about Django and, while reading the docs, I found a way to execute raw queries with [`Manager.raw`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw).

So, basically, we can do:

```
>>> foo_raw_queryset = Foo.objects.raw("select * from myapp_foo")
>>> foo_raw_query_set  # needs some list comprehension
<RawQuerySet: select * from myapp_foo>
>>> foo_list = [f for f in foo_raw_queryset] # will return a model object list
>>> foo_list
[<Foo: um>, <Foo: dois>]
```

Therefore, I don't know if it's the best solution for problems like yours, but you can run your custom query without the `IN` statement and avoid the error you're facing from MySQL.